# Iterar un bucle con un numero empezado por 0

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Les comento el siguiente problema: Estoy usando una API de clima para mostrar el clima durante las próximas 12hs (Usando React). Lo que la API me trae son tres arrays con 24 elementos de una hora cada uno. Lo que yo quiero hacer es tomar la hora de este momento especifico como hora inicial y a partir de ahí usar solo los 12 elementos que le siguen. Si no puedo completar estas 12 hs con horas del dia de hoy, uso hs del próxima día.

Hasta acá todo perfecto. El tema es que esta API me da la hora con un string que dice así:

```
"localtime": "2022-02-01 15:52"
```

Lo que yo estoy haciendo es separar ese string en partes y usar solo la parte de la hora (del 15:52 me quedo solo con el 15) y desde ahi quedarme con la hora 15,16,17,18,19 ...etc.
Esto lo hago con la siguiente linea de codigo:

```
horaLocal: Number((data.location.localtime).substring(11, 13))
```

El problema que estoy teniendo ahora es cuando la hora local empieza con el numero 0, por ejemplo las 04:15. Acá mi linea de código me retorna NaN.

Hago un pequeño edit para aclarar algo: La hora la saco de la respuesta de la API y no de getHours() para obtener la hora local de la ciudad que quiera ver.

Segundo Edit, agrego el procedimiento por el cual el bucle for se llena con las 12hs:

1- La API me devuelve por cada llamada un array "forecast" con 3 arrays adentro, cada uno de ellos contiene las 24hs de cada dia
2- Almaceno los 72 elementos en this.state.pronostico.
3- Separo en 2 arrays los pronosticos de "hoy" y "mañana" con este codigo:

```
const limpiarInfo = () => {
        const data = []
        this.state.pronostico.forEach(e => {
            data.push(e.hour)
        })
        return data.flat()
    }


todasLasHorasHoy.push(limpiarInfo().filter(e => e.time.includes(diaHoy)))
todasLasHorasMañana.push(limpiarInfo().filter(e => e.time.includes(diaMañana)))
```

4- Despues de hacer eso itero los arrays de hoy y mañana para obtener las proximas 12 hs a partir de la hora actual:

```
for (let i = (this.state.horaLocal + 1); i < (this.state.horaLocal + 12); i++) {
        if (i === 24) {
            break;
        } else {
            listaHorasHoy.push(todasLasHorasHoy[0][i])
        }
    }
    if (listaHorasHoy.length < 11) {
        for (let j = 0; listaHorasHoy.length < 12; j++) {
            listaHorasHoy.push(todasLasHorasMañana[0][j])
        }
    }
```

Y aca es donde entro de vuelta en el mismo problema, como puedo hacer para iterar ese bucle for con el valor "horaLocal" si cuando la hora empieza con 0 no me lo incluye a ese 0 y me devuelve, por ejemplo 8 en vez de 08.

Alguien sabe como podría solucionar esto? Gracias.

Comment: ¿De que tipo es `data.location.localtime`? si es `string` como lo mencionas, no deberia dar `NaN`, x ejemplo `08` resultaría en `8`, con la linea de código que compartes. Si pudieras confirmar.

Comment: Ese es el problema, que el valor 8 en vez de 08 no me sirve porque no lo puedo usar en el bucle for

Comment: Si se itera `horaLocal` con por ejemplo 7, se tiene una iteración de 8 a 18 en `i`,ahora bien  ¿Aquí que se supone que hay `todasLasHorasHoy[0][i]`? Estoy tratando de comprender como se usa `listaHorasHoy`.

Comment: todasLasHorasHoy es el resultado de: juntar los 2 arrays que tienen las 24 hs del dia de hoy y las 24 del dia de mañana. Quizas el nombre "todasLasHorasHoy" no fue el correcto.

Answer (score 0):

A continuación te muestro la posible solución:

En resumen sería convertir el valor que estás recibiendo a tipo Date y obtener las horas y minutos (y concatenarlo usando template strings).

```js
horaLocal: new Date(`${localtime?.getHours()}:${localtime?.getMinutes()}`)
```

Comment: Sigue ocurriendo lo mismo, si tomo el valor y lo uso en un nuevo new Date() me retorna NaN (Siempre hablando de la hora que empieza en 0, si lo hago con cualquier ubicacion que la hora no empiece en 0 sirve)

Comment: Si introduces localtime tal cual como te llega no debería ocurrir, al menos que localtime sea NaN el cual ya sería un problema de la API. Confirma que el valor que estas recibiendo es tal cual como lo describes, haciendo un console.log antes de hacer la transformación.

Comment: Recuerda que tienes que sustituir todo lo que tienes en horaLocal simplemente.

Comment: Agregue ahi el codigo que estoy usando para iterar y conseguir las proximas 12 hs a partir de la actual.